# Logically enough answer for the question.

Tags: real-analysis, logic, metric-spaces, solution-verification

**The question:**

Let $A$ be a mapping of a metric space $R$ into itself. Prove that the condition $$\rho(Ax,Ay)<\rho(x,y),\quad (x\neq y)$$
is insufficient for the existence of a fixed point of $A$.

**My response:**

Let $$A(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}$$

First observe $A'(x)=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}< 1, \forall x\in \mathbb R^+$

Now using mean value theorem from calculus, $\exists c\in \mathbb R^+$ such that

$$\rho(Ax,Ay)=|A(x)-A(y)|=|A'(c)||x-y|<|x-y|=\rho(x,y)$$

However $A(x)$ has no fixed point because if it had then $A(x)=x$ would implied $x^2=1+x^2$ which is impossible.

**My Actual Question:** In a logical way, is not that counter example for the given question? I mean, am I missing some point that maybe I should have proved this for a generic $A$? I think my example is enough for the question but the lecturer says that "You should show this for general $A$", **Why?**

Comment: If you want to disprove a statement, giving a counterexample, then it is sufficient to give **just one** counterexample. So I think you are correct. (Note: I didn't check the details of your verification that your map $A$ is in the required conditions.)